# Guidance on E-Commerce project language and frameworks

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, e-commerce

I'm gonna develop an e-commerce website, and also I need to develop a mobile app for the same. Which language is preferable for both the front end and back end for this development. Initially, I planned to develop using `react.js, node.js and MongoDB` for the web app, and react native for mobile app. But I did some research, I got confused. FYI I have good knowledge in `html, css, JS` and `dot net`.

Comment: This calls for opinion based answers... not sure SO is the best place for that kind of question.

Comment: @FelDev what is SO?

Comment: He is mentioning stack overflow (SO). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @FelDev. Your question is basically begging for opinionated (and possibly biased) answers.

To avoid an opinionated answer, what I would do in your situation is to think farther ahead.

I would ask myself questions like... if this store ends up being popular, will so and so features offered by this framework/language be good when it comes to performance? how about scalability? also maintenance?

For a more opinionated answer, I think I would agree with you (assuming this is for a company you are working with). ReactJS is very popular on the frontend so future employees will most likely be easier to find. If not, just use whatever you like that gets the job done. If it's for educational purposes to enhance your capabilities, why not try something new by letting this be a chance to learn a new framework? etc.

I hope this helps sort of :).